# Javascript slidetoggle reset every interval of ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

in short,
i have a `html table` which has its rows populated by an ajax call, which has a timeout of 1000ms.

on each row there is an additional row below which, on click (`slidetoggle`), shows additional data from the `ajax` call (click for more info on list etc, click again to hide)

eveytime the timeout resets & a new call is made, the table is reset & the additional display is not shown by default (`css - display: none`).

how can i change this to remember which row's slide toggles are open at the time of reset, and stay that way?

```
$(document).on('click', '.referral', function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```
.referral //refers to the table rows
$(this).next() //refers to the additional information display
```

Comment: It is better if you can share jsfiddle and html code.

Comment: i'm having trouble getting jsfiddle to work, i will post up when i can

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.referral', function() {    
    var $additionalRow = $(this).next();
    $additionalRow.next().slideToggle("slow");

    // hide all other additional row except $additionalRow
    $('.referral').next().not($additionalRow).hide();
});
```